# React User Context not working with login authentication

Tags: reactjs

**Login.jsx**

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext)
const navigate = useNavigate()

console.log(user)

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try{
        const {data} = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/user/login",{
            email, password
        })
        setUser(data)
        console.log(data)
        console.log(user)
        alert("Login Success")
        navigate("/")
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        alert("Failed to Login")
    }
}
```

**UserContext.jsx**

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext({})

const UserContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({})

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{user,setUser}}>
        {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default UserContextProvider
```

**App.js**

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <UserContextProvider>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
    </UserContextProvider> 
  </BrowserRouter>
```

I am trying to use `UserContext` to fetch the login data from the login page after clicking the login button. Even I tried to use `setUser` to the login data and I `console.log(user)` it shows nothing and after refresh it lost state. May I ask any solutions can log the user in and store the state when refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update

For persisting the user login data, you will need to utilize either cookie, or local storage, simply because React doesn't persist any data on a reload.

For example

```js
// auth.js
class AuthService {
  login(username, password) {
    // Perform authentication, e.g., make an API request to validate the user
    if (username === 'user' && password === 'password') {
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({ username }));
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
  }

  getUser() {
    const user = localStorage.getItem('user');
    return user ? JSON.parse(user) : null;
  }
}

export default new AuthService();
```

Then in your `Homepage` component, check the user login status

```js
function Homepage() {
  const user = AuthService.getUser();

  // if user session is invalid, redirect to login page
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  if (!user) navigate('/login')

  ... rest of your code
}
```

---

> Even I tried to use setUser to the login data and I console.log(user) it showed nothing

This is expected ReactJS behavior because you are trying to console log a state that hasn't been updated by the `setState`. The state `user` is only available on the next render, not the same render.

You can try to move the `console.log(user)` on the context file, it will the console log the updated `user` on the next rerender triggered by the `setUser` you executed in `Login` component.

> ... and after refresh it lost state.

This is also expected because the state doesn't persist after the current session, or after a reload of the page.

> May I ask if any solutions can log the user in and store the state when refreshing the page?

Looks like you are already doing everything correctly, if you don't mind providing even more info, we will be able to assist you further. (such as possible import path misspell, syntax error elsewhere)

Comment: Even I tried to ```console.log(user)``` out of the block it still shows nothing

Comment: @Dom even in the context file?

Comment: In the context file it could print out but after refresh lost state

Comment: @Dom I see the missing piece, answer has been updated hopefully that explains things a bit better